# change legend's name of jfreechart

Tags: java

I'm working on a graphic (`JFreeChart`) in Java. I would like to rename the legend of a chart and I don't know how.
Currently I have the default name "1" but I want to change the "Team BO".

Comment: you have to post what you have tried :)

Comment: i dont know how to begin.

Comment: The `LegendTitle` object from JFreeChart may help you. [Doc is here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/title/LegendTitle.html). Also take a look at the `addLegend()` method from the `JFreeChart` class